# Jquery Autocomplete not displaying results in textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a textbox on which I am wanting to perform autocomplete using JQuery and AJAX.  Upon entering a value, the AJAX call is successfully made and results are found as you can see from FireBug below.  The returned values are however not displayed in the textbox, and there are no error messages. Would appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Below is what I have on the UI side

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb_BType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("BType") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" onkeyup="BTAutoComplete(this.value,  $('#ddl_BManufacturer :selected').text(), 'tb_BType')" />
```

Here is what I have for the JQuery side, which resides on the Site.Master (as it will be used throughout the site).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function BTAutoComplete(searchTerm, qualifier, objID) {
            var obj = $('#' + objID).val();

            if (obj) {
                $('#' + objID).autocomplete({
                    delay: 5,
                    minLength: 0,
                    disabled: false,
                    source: function (request, response) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "WebServices/Impact.asmx/GetTypes",
                            data: "{'_bType': '" + request.term + "','_manufacturer': '" + qualifier + "'}",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (result) {
                                response(result.d);
                            },

                            error: function (result) {
                                console.log("AJAX Autocomplete errror!")
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("The object " + objID + " is undefined.");
            }
        }
</script>
```

[image]